# Python append xls file using only xlwt/xlrd

Tags: python, excel, python-3.4, xlrd, xlwt

I am having problems appending issues appending data to an `xls` file.
Long story short, I am using a program to get some data from something and writing it in an `xls` file.

If I run the script 10 times, I would like the results to be appended to the same xls file.

My problem is that I am forced to use Python 3.4 and `xlutils` is not supported, so I cannot use the copy function.

I just have to use `xlwt` / `xlrd`. Note, the file cannot be a `xlsx`.

Is there any way i can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would look into using openpyxl, which is supported by Python 3.4.  An example of appending to a file can be found https://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/default/.  Please also see:  [How to append to an existing excel sheet with XLWT in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21856559/how-to-append-to-an-existing-excel-sheet-with-xlwt-in-python).  Here is an example that will do it.  Assuming you have an Excel sheet called sample.xlsx:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook


# grab the active worksheet
wb = load_workbook("sample.xlsx")
ws = wb.active
ws.append([3])

# Save the file
wb.save("sample.xlsx")
```

Comment: i need a .xls file; not a xlsx

Comment: once i get about doing it i will get back here with my code.